# Send Base64 string to WCF Service From WP7 App

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

Hello Friends i am working on wp7 application in which i am browsing an image from media library , getting Base64 string of it and sending it to WCF Service to upload it at server but i am not able to send long Base64 string to web service i got following error :   "The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'UploadFile'. The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 23083."
Please help solve the problem.

Comment: Have you seen this ? : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/da9b5252-de00-498d-b6b7-d256de47b8c6/

Comment: When i add reference ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file is created which is not having <readerQuotas> tag supported in it.so i am not able to set this tag.

Answer (score 1):

That is a configuration issue in your application on the server side.

You'll have to edit the web.config file and change the binding [readerQuotas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731325.aspx) element in order to increase the max* values.

It should be something like this:

```xml
<readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
```

Comment: its already set in my WCF Service's Web.Config file but then also i am getting error from my WP7 App when i send long Base64string

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if this will work..but you can try sending data in chunks(less than 8192 bytes) to the service and then sum it up at the service end to regenerate the file. I mean use the logic to download a file synchronously and that may help..Not a WP guy here, but seems like a possible solution.